# speed up jQuery load function

Tags: jquery, load

i am using jQuery load to load tooltips from other sites.
Unfortunatly it takes almost 20 seconds until my last tooltip is finished.

Is there any way to speed this up?

**Edit:**
Here is a fiddle:

```
jsfiddle.net/bto82pjy/1/
```

Of course this script is fast. It loads a id of the same page. In my example i load several divs of another page.
There you can see the tooltips loading when you click on a information sign:
http://www.austrokamin.at/bausatz-edelstahlkamin-standard-150mm.html

Comment: code? more information about it? like what exactly do you load?

Comment: I edited my post. Habe you got any idea, please?

Comment: any news on your progress?

Comment: Yes. I solved it with php.
Though my cms needs to load a lot of products it is MUCH faster than to load content with javascript

Answer (score 0):

According to what i see in Chrome DevTools, you seem to load whole product pages with your `ajax` for no reason (they are not displayed in the tooltips).

for example, your are loading: http://www.austrokamin.at/catalog/product/view/id/1462,
http://www.austrokamin.at/catalog/product/view/id/1439
and so on.

[image: Chrome DevTools Network-Tab]

But he data displayed in your tooltips is coming from `<div>` containers further down in your code:

[image: Div Containers for your Tooltips]

So you don't need your `jQuery` / `ajax` code at all, and can speed up your pageload by a lot.

(*you seem to be from austria, that's funny - i am from austria too*)

Comment: Hi.
No I have a link there, for example:

<a class="ajax zeichnung" href="/catalog/product/view/id/5494">Abmessungen Prüföffnung</a>

Comment: where? look at the link [http://www.austrokamin.at/catalog/product/view/id/1439](http://www.austrokamin.at/catalog/product/view/id/1439) - this content is never showed on your page and not in any tooltip, so you don't need to load it.

Comment: It is shown.

Look at this page:
http://www.austrokamin.at/bausatz-edelstahlkamin-standard-150mm.html

All the drawings and tables inside the tooltips come from another site.

Just open the last but one tooltip (Durchdurchführungen) and then wait for i dont know maybe 30 seconds.

Comment: maybe i'll take a deeper look into it, when i am at home. but still: there is something different shown, not the product pages you are loading as well. http://www.austrokamin.at/catalog/product/view/id/1439 is never shown inside a tooltip, but you are still loading it with ajax.

Comment: Not the whole product page is shown, just click on "Abmessungen". 
The content inside <div id="abmessungen">...</div> is loaded.

Comment: ok, but you are still loading the whole product page in order to just show a little bit from its content. maybe you can change it, so that it only loads the needed content, not the whole product pages. this would make it much faster. (and I am at work right now, maybe i can take a closer look when I am at home. it's hard to debug such a huge piece of code, maybe you got the time and extract the code to a `JSFiddle`)

Comment: Hi, i updated my topic and added a fiddle.
I have no idea how not to load the whole page. As far as i understand, the whole page is always loaded. Just take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/ (loading page fragments)
Maybe you have an idea when you take a look at my fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: well, the easiest solution would be to create extra pages with just the content needed that you need for your tooltips. when you got some server-side-scripting language as well (e.g. `PHP`) then this would be quite simple to do.